# Get the path of file located in src folder of webapplication using spring.

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How to get the full path of file located in /src/reportpackage/daysheet.jasper in the spring mvc application?. How to get the string format of the path?

Comment: Are you using Netbeans or Eclipse?

Comment: Try right click and properties

Comment: Thank u for reply.I should retrieve path through code itself @DakshShah

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that after the build your file would end up in classpath and what you would be loading through Spring resource loading mechanism is a classpath resource. You can use spring notation for it like this

```
appContext.getResource("classpath:reportpackage/daysheet.jasper");
```

where appContext is the spring application context which can be autowired in any Spring bean